# Kendo Grid text selection inside cell / table with multiselection enabled

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, kendo-ui

I would like to make text selection possible inside grid with multirow selection enabled.
My solution to this problem is to use for example CTRL key to temporary disable multi selection, use single row selection to enable default text selection mechanisms.

I do not know if there is a solution to change grid options after it is being initialized (and I couldn't figure it out myself)
I use Kendo MVC in C# and Razor extension to create the grid.
Any ideas?

Comment: "CTRL key to temporary disable multi selection"  Classic behaviour is to use Ctrl button to ENABLE multi selection. Your idea could really confuse your users

Comment: I know.. this kinda suck, maybe something like in [link]http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/selecting/defaultcs.aspx (works only in IE) press CTRL and select some data

Comment: It could be SHIFT, ALT this doesn't matter to me

Answer (score 1):

Use the same approach as the one suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279285/avoid-right-click-on-kendo-grid/14279587#14279587) question. Basically for your case it would look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').tbody.on('mousedown',function(e){
        if(e.ctrlKey){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation()
        }
    })
})
```