# Avoid right click on kendo grid

Tags: jquery, telerik, kendo-ui

This is my grid:

```
$("#myHtmlTable1").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        pageSize: 18
    },
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    selectable: true,
    pageable: {
        input: false,
        numeric: false
    },
    change: function () {
        // MY LOGIC
    },
    columns: [
    {
        field: "Col1",
        width: 40
    },
    {
        field: "Col2",
        width: 250
    },
    {
        width: 40,
        field: "Col3"
    },
    {
        width: 150,
        field: "Col4"
    }
    ]
});
```

When I clic a row I get the row text and I put it in another textbox. But I want to do this only with left button mouse so that I can see the source code page using the right clic over the grid.

Answer (score 5):

You can attach the following keydown handler to the tbody element of the Grid when the document event is triggered to prevent the right click mousedown event from bubling and thus avoid the Grid reacting to it.

```
$(function(){
    $('#myHtmlTable1').data('kendoGrid').tbody.on('mousedown',function(e){
        if(e.button==2){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation()
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: BTW. What does it mean `KendoGrid` inside `.data()`?

Comment: This is the core which gives you all the client functionality for a widget. Everything is stored in that jQuery data object. I suggest you to search the documentation for more information. Here is what will give you the basic idea http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-widgets#getting-the-widget-client-object